# PHP Closing Tag: =?>

Tags: php, php-shorttags

I've just seen [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#91606) on php.net, which contains the following snippet of code:

```
</head>
<?= ob_flush(); =?>
<body>
```

I've not seen the `=?>` used before (I'm fine with the `<?=`, that's obvious) and when I put it in a test file it gave a syntax error. So, is this just a typo, or is there any situation where this is syntactically valid?

Comment: I'd say it's a typo but I'll let those with more clout weight in on the situation.

Comment: *Geek Moment* Funniest thing Ive seen in a while

Comment: @RyanMurphy Yeah, it's either something really obscure but valid, or just plain wrong :P I figured it was unlikely to be valid, but worth checking heh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typo.

There is *a lot* of **junk** in php.net comments.

As of recently, it's now possible to vote on [comments on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#91606).

Comment: Emphasis added...  After spending time here on SO I always wish for editability on php.net.

Comment: Sounds good, cheers for the clarification. I'll accept when it lets me :)

Comment: php.net comments would really benefit from SO style voting.

Comment: @AD7six sorry for trying to contact you this way; I've posted a question on StackOverflow with a possible bug in CakePHP. Not 100% sure though, if you have the time, are you able to check? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247587/code-coverage-analysis-not-working-for-plugin-unit-tests-in-cakephp-2-2-7

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that's one of the thousands of php.net's comments typos.

Comment: PHP's docs are fine, there are typos in the user-submitted comments.